# Prolog remove character spaces from atom for using term_to_atom

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

At some point of my program I have an atom formed by what previously were also atoms, and I want to remove the character spaces within it so that later I can use without any problem:

`term_to_atom(Result, 'second2(second2),region(ºMediterranean Sea),months(no_value),third3(third3),recog(ºNew Type),distance(no_value)').`

and obtain this

`Result = (second2(second2), region(ºMediterraneanSea), months(no_value), third3(third3), recog(ºNewType), distance(no_value))`

or also the original would work

`Result = (second2(second2), region(ºMediterranean Sea), months(no_value), third3(third3), recog(ºNew Type), distance(no_value))`

because if I don't delete those character spaces then `term_to_atom` will complain about it. How can I solve it?

Comment: I think your problem are the `º` characters. Wouldn't this be what you meant: `term_to_atom(Result, 'second2(second2),region(''Mediterranean Sea''),months(no_value),third3(third3),recog(''New Type''),distance(no_value)').`

Comment: those `º` characters are there on purpose, and they are used as id's for the database, they are not the problem in this case, because with or without them term_to_atom complains in the space characters. I cannot use the double quote solution because that is not what my program receives. What it receives is exactly the atom mentioned above.

Comment: and also other values like `region(ºAtlantic Ocean)` or `recog(ºOld Type)`. Or other examples with more than one character space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this procedure:

```
strip_spaces(S, NoSpaces) :-
   atom_codes(S, Cs), delete(Cs, 0' , X), atom_codes(NoSpaces, X).
```

but delete/3 is deprecated. Another possibility is

```
strip_spaces(S, NoSpaces) :-
    atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', S),
    atomic_list_concat(L, NoSpaces).
```

Either of these will 'eat' each space, but from your problem description, in comments you exchanged with gusbro, this doesn't seems to me the right way to go. Changing the literals seems at DB interface could ask for trouble later.

Parsing your input to a list, instead of a conjunction, can be done with DCGs:

```
:- [library(http/dcg_basics)].

parse_result(X, R) :-
    atom_codes(X, Cs),
    phrase(parse_list(R), Cs).
parse_list([T|Ts]) -->
    parse_term(T), (",", parse_list(Ts) ; {Ts=[]}).
parse_term(T) -->
    string(F), "(", string(Arg), ")",
    {atom_codes(Fa,F), atom_codes(Arga,Arg), T =.. [Fa,Arga]}.
```

Comment: yeap, exactly what I needed, thanks. well I also use the character `º` doing `string_concat('º', Region, IDReg)` because term_to_atom will lose the name of Region when the first character is a capital letter (it will consider it as a Variable), and I need that name later. Now with your help everything works smoothly  :)